# Let $R$ be an infinite comutative ring with unity, $M,N$ be $R$-modules, $f:M \to N$ be a surjective module homomorphism; then $|M|=|N ||\ker f|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, modules, cardinals

Let $R$ be an infinite commutative ring with unity, $M,N$ be modules over $R$, let $f:M \to N$ be a surjective module homomorphism; then is it true that $|M|=|N || \ker f|$   ($M,N$ are not necessarily finite ) ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem_3

Comment: You'll need to use a version of Lagrange's Theorem once you apply the isomorphism theorem.

Comment: What do you denote $\lvert M\rvert$ in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on a cell phone so let the kernel be $A$. Using the axiom of choice, construct a set $N'$ consisting of one element from each coset of $A$. There is an obvious bijection of $N'$ with $N$. Then every element of $M$ can be represented uniquely as the sum of an element of $N'$ and an element of $A$, hence there is a bijection between $N'\times A$ and $M$ defined by $(n,a)\mapsto n+a$. Since $|N'\times A|=|N||A|$, the result follows.